# How to stored data from server to android sqlite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am developing app which include server data and every screen it connect to server and fetch the data so its take a long time to load.E.g app like RSS reader.

Application need to fetch data from server but for the better performance i want to stored that data on android database and after next log in if i am connecting to server its just update the information,am i going in right direction? now every time i should be fetch the data run-time and its taking so much time.

So please help me.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: i am trying to stored server data to my sqlite database and update that info every time

Comment: good! and what issue are you facing?